# Decorator Pattern For UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I was wondering if anyone has ever attempted to or thought of using the decorator pattern to make it easier to DRY up UITableView code.

What I'm thinking of is creating a set of reusable decorators for UITableViewCells, for instance one for adding background gradients, one for adding different shadings,  and a variety of other stylings.

You would then be able to chain the decorators together, to get the desired effect, instead of having to bolt on some Frankenstein code to different objects every time you wanted to reuse similar design styles.

Does this make sense, or am I just recreating the wheel?  I really dislike subclassing UITableViewCells, and think this would be a good way to get around that problem.

I'd love to hear the opinion of some of you guys who have way more Objective-C and UIKit experience than I do on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the decorator pattern typically based around an *abstract* base or interface/protocol at the root? Since your base here isn't exchangeable (it must be a `UITableViewCell`) this could be tricky.

Maybe you can pull it off by proxying, i.e. subclassing `NSProxy` to wrap a `UITableViewCell`. I don't know if that will work, as UIKit classes tend to be quite tightly integrated with one another. The proxy and the the real cell will have different identities, and if the cell sends messages to the table view with `self` as an argument, this could confuse the table view.

Another option is to subclass the table view cell once to add some kind of extensible delegate mechanism whereby you can dynamicall add delegates to each cell. I'm calling them delegates as they won't subclass from the table cell, just add a behaviour for it. You would then intercept messages to the cell and decide dynamically, based on the delegates present in the object, whether a delegate receives the message or whether it goes directly to the superclass (`UITableViewCell`) method implementation. You could define a protocol for each delegate which declares the new methods/properties the thusly extended cell will accept.

I don't know how much trouble this would be to implement in the first place, and how complicated the code for each delegate would be. I guess you'd have to try it to see if it's worth it in practice.

In any case, mixing in behaviours to UIKit classes would definitely be an interesting and useful thing to have. For my own apps, I've built an automatic view layouting system which lays out views depending on their content, the available space and certain resizing parameters. Something like this would probably reduce the amount of repeated code in that system somewhat.

Comment: I was considering using a category to do this, which would use a  singleton for storing the relationships between a decorator and cell.

Answer (score 0):

While this approach is sound from an architectural point of view, in the reality of iOS it has a terrible effect on performance (it has been attempted before and did not end well). iOS caches pre-rendered bits of tableview cells as much as possible, so performing runtime modifications of the layout and appearance of different cells in a way that the designers of the UIKit did not anticipate would destroy that caching, and performance would suffer.

Take a look at how [Matt Gallagher handles custom cell drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html), his approach has been pseudo-blessed by Apple at WWDC this year. Also, watch the "Tips and tricks to improve responsiveness" and "Understanding UIKit rendering" [sessions from WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), as they address real world techniques for improving performance of UITableView.